# XSS Issues while redirecting to a new URL

Tags: jsp, xss

I am working on an old jsp application which contains code similar to following:

```
<%
    String ref = request.getParameter("ref");
    response.sendRedirect(ref);
%>
```

The parameter ref is clearly visible in the URL and anyone can edit it. According to OWASP security standards, this code is vulnerable to XSS attacks. As per OWASP:
This vulnerability could be used as part of a phishing scam by redirecting users to a malicious site. If no validation is applied, a malicious user could create a hyperlink to redirect your users to an unvalidated malicious website.

In my case this is being used only for the logout page. And in any case the malicious user cannot control this paramneter for any other user's session. Also, this variable's value is not being controlled by user input.

Please share your thoughts if this is still a XSS vulnerability or not ?

Comment: you can use requestDispatcher

Comment: I am not sure how that is going to help in removing the XSS issue, if there is any in this case. Anyways, thanks for the input, but my question is the scenario that I mentioned is really a XSS vulnerabiltity or not ?

Comment: "in any case the malicious user cannot control this paramneter for any other user's session" — What stops the attacker from sending the user a link (via email or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

It is vulnerable to XSS in older browsers, and HTTP response splitting and open redirection in all browsers.

The problem is that `response.sendRedirect()` sends a 301 http response with a `Location:` header, and this way, a user can craft a link that will hava javascript code which will be run upon certain actions in certain browsers (clicking a link in the browser error page, clicking reload, etc). See details [here](http://websecurity.com.ua/3386/) (attacks #4-#8). I think this does not work anymore in recent browsers though.

However, it is still vulnerable to [HTTP response splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting) (sometimes header injection) as an attacker can insert a newline character in the parameter and thus may be able to add response headers to the application response.

It is also trivially vulnerable to [open redirection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect). An attacker can craft a link to the application domain that will redirect the victim user to any website the attacker chooses.